# Include файлов в JS?

Tags: jquery, include, javascript

Есть два файла: 
`myjs_file.js` и файл `lang_RU.js`.

Как можно заинклудить языковой файл **lang_RU.js** в первый файл?

Comment: [$.getScript()][1] или обычный $.ajax() с **dataType = 'script'**. Только не забывайте про асинхронность.

   [1]:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Это хорошая практика?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, всё зависит от конкретной задачи и обстоятельств. Если у вас есть возможность изначально подключить файл, то зачем извращаться? Но, если такой возможности нет, то куда деваться? 

Например, у вас есть несколько файлов с локализациями. Вы хотите подключать нужный файл динамически. Да, вполне нормально подгружать указанным выше способом, **НО** ведь можно их все собрать в один файл объектом и выбирать нужную локаль в зависимости от настроек. Согласны? А что лучше будет для вас - я не знаю.